# Using ToListAsync with MongoDb and AutoMapper ProjectTo

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper with a MongoDb collection, however I am having problems using the ToListAsync method.
I have the following code:

```cs
            IMongoCollection<Category> categoryCollection = 
                database.GetCollection<Category>(settings.CategoriesCollectionName);

            IMongoQueryable<Category> categories = 
                categoryCollection.AsQueryable();

            var categoriesProjectionQuery = 
                categories.ProjectTo<CategoryDto>(this.mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

            var categoriesList = 
                await categoriesProjectionQuery.ToListAsync();
```

This code does not compile. It only works with the sync version of `ToList()`, and not `ToListAsync()`. AutoMapper `ProjectTo`, returns an `IQueryable`, and Mongo Driver does not seem to be able to use that in the provided `ToListAsync()` (which expects a `IMongoQueryable` collection)

Am I missing something? Is this not possible?

Note: I am using AutoMapper 9.0.0 and MongoDB.Driver 2.10.2

Comment: Did you try casting to `IMongoQueryable`?

Comment: Uau. I feel stupid... It worked!